# Distance / Energy of particle when popping bubble

Tags: classical-mechanics, surface-tension, bubbles

Hi when I am putting the Dishwashing liquid on the sponge it sometimes makes such small bubble like 5mm in the diameter that pops afterwards and I always wonder if it is possible that the particles of the popping liquid might fly so long (distance of outstretched hand) and hit the eye (because I am watching it).

Is there any physical equation that manages this? The energy of particles when popping bubble? I guess it is related to diameter, maybe also to some chemical properties (or not).

I guess it might be little bit similar to drop of radio signal strength (meaning it is weaker with each meter squared or something like that, as the bubble is 360 degrees).

It is little bit Obsessive Compulsive Disorder (OCD) question but still, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

I asked on google "the mechanics of bursting bubbles" and a number of publications come up. [Example](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4902820) from the abstract:

> Bubbles at a free surface usually burst in ejecting myriads of droplets. Focusing on the bubble bursting jet, prelude for these aerosols, we propose a simple scaling for the jet velocity and we unravel experimentally the intricate roles of bubble shape, capillary waves, gravity, and liquid properties. We demonstrate that droplets ejection unexpectedly changes with liquid properties. In particular, using damping action of viscosity, self-similar collapse can be sheltered from capillary ripples and continue closer to the singular limit, therefore producing faster and smaller droplets. These results pave the road to the control of the bursting bubble aerosols.

....

> Two distinct types of droplets are involved, lying on two different mechanisms appearing during bubble bursting. When the thin liquid film—the bubble cap—separating the bubble from the atmosphere disintegrates, film drops are produced with radius mainly less than 1 μm. Then the resulting opened cavity collapses and a jet emerges producing jet drops by breaking up (see Fig. 1 and corresponding Multimedia view). For example, this latter mechanism accounts for the majority of sea-spray aerosol particles in the atmosphere with radius between 1 and 25 μm.

From the last sentence the answer to your question is that yes, some of the aerosol particles could hit you in the eye.